# Laravel 5.2 - Mutators - SetAttribute

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following mutator method in my `Information` Model: (User has `information` method)

```
public function setMyDateAttribute($value){
      $this->attributes['my_date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
}
```

And

```
$user->information()->update($request->get('information'));
```

But nothing happens...

But if I do:

```
$information = $request->get('information');
$information['my_date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $information['my_date']);
$user->information()->update($information);
```

it works perfect

What I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing but from the example given in your question, I guessed that, you want `Laravel` to take care of your `my_date` field just like (created-at/updated_at) timestamps. If so, then you should ad the `my_date` name in `$dates` fields in your model for example:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'my_date'];
```

If you are using the `softDeleting` then also add the `deleted_at` in that `$dates` array. [Read more here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

Comment: I have "my_date" in $dates. But with "SetMyDateAttribute" is not working. But If I do it manual works.

Comment: Make sure it's a `timestamp` field in database.